# How to get rows with minimum ID on a multiple columns query

Tags: sql, sql-server, min, group

I have a table like this:

| Id | Type | multiple columns (a lot)... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |  |
| 2 | 50 |  |
| 3 | 50 |  |
| 4 | 75 |  |
| 5 | 75 |  |
| 6 | 75 |  |

I need to get only the rows with the older (min) id as a part of my query. The result should include all the columns of the table, but given that these multiple columns have multiple values, it's not posible to use MIN() and then GROUP BY

I need something like this:

| Id | Type | multiple columns (a lot)... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |  |
| 4 | 75 |  |

I've tried using MIN() function and grouping by but that's not an option cause the rest of the columns have different values and if I use a GROUP BY I'm getting all the rows and not only the ones with the lowest ID's.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `min over` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WITH TIES` option in concert with the window function `lag() over()`

To be clear, this will flag when the value changes

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From YourTable
 Order by case when lag([type],1) over (order by id) = [Type] then 0 else 1 end desc
```

**Results**

```
Id  Type
1   50
4   75
```

Based on Rodrigo's solution, you may have wanted the first `[Type]` regardless of sequence.

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order by row_number() over (partition by [Type] order by ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column that represents the number of dups.
That result will be used to join only with unique rows.
You can use Common table Expression to split the steps

```
WITH rows_with_index AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type) AS row_number,
    id,
    Type
FROM
    <TABLE>
ORDER BY 2
) 
SELECT * FROM rows_with_index t 
 WHERE rows_with_index.row_number = 1;
```

Comment: This may very well be the solution OP is looking for.  Just a couple of items:  1) row_number() requires an ORDER BY  2) <type> should really be [Type]  3) Since you have row_number, no need for the JOIN, just WHERE row_number=1

Comment: I think you can't add a WHERE clause on row_number, but I will edit the other suggestions! Thank you

Comment: Select * from cte where row_number = 1  ... you do get that extra column

Comment: You're right! Now I got it

Comment: Still need order by in row_number()